# Pulling C/C++ standard library into your project namespace, good idea?

Tags: c++, namespaces, porting

I'm porting some open source code so that it can build on another c++ compiler. One of the difficulties and themes that seem to keep cropping up are implementation differences of the provided standard library by the compiler.

For example, one of the source files that I'm compiling includes `<sys/types.h>`. However, it gives me the following errors:

```
Error E2316 g:\Borland\BCC593\Include\sys/types.h 45: 'time_t' is not a member of 'std'
Error E2272 g:\Borland\BCC593\Include\sys/types.h 45: Identifier expected
```

After looking at the root cause of this I found that one of the main include headers of the project is including `<sys/types.h>` in this pattern:

project_source1.cpp:

```
#include "../TargetPlatform.h"
#include "project_config.h"
#include <windows.h>

namespace project_namespace {
#include "project_component/all.h"
// more project includes down here
// ...
}
```

project_component/all.h:

```
#ifndef INCLUDE_GUARDS
#define INCLUDE_GUARDS

#include <sys/types.h>
#include "project_header1.h"
#include "project_header2.h"
// and other headers etc..
// followed with class definitions and what not.

#endif
```

This is all well and good except for one problem, the `<sys/types.h>` is implemented something like this for the compiler I'm porting to:

`<sys/types.h>` trimmed to the essence:

```
namespace std {

typedef long time_t;
typedef short dev_t;
typedef short ino_t;
typedef short mode_t;
typedef short nlink_t;
typedef int   uid_t;
typedef int   gid_t;
typedef long  off_t;

} // std

using std::time_t;
using std::dev_t;
using std::ino_t;
using std::mode_t;
using std::nlink_t;
using std::uid_t;
using std::gid_t;
using std::off_t;
```

And this is the cause of the compile error I'm seeing. Because the project is including `<sys/types.h>` *inside* its own namespace, things like  time_t, off_t, dev_t etc get put into the scope `project_namespace::std::` which is obviously not what's intended.

What's the best way to handle this? Keep in mind there could be other standard library headers defined in a similar fashion and not just `sys/types.h`. Are there any C++ idioms that's relevant or semi-related to this issue(or possibly even at odds with it due to the way this is implemented)? If so, how can it be reconciled?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a bad idea. Do not do things this way. Put the namespace declarations inside each header file. Never have a `#include` directive inside the scope of a namespace.

Never is a strong word, and there are very rare cases in which you might want to do this. If the file you're `#include`ing also has `#include` directives, you almost certainly do not want to be doing this, even more so than if they didn't.

If you need to be able to easily rename your namespace or use the same header to declare the same symbols in several different namespaces depending on context, use the preprocessor to change the namespace name instead. That's extremely ugly to do, but much better than what you're currently doing.

One thing you can do as a quick and dirty solution to this is `#include <sys/types.h>` and any other system header that's included before the namespace declaration. This will cause the double-inclusion guards in the system header files to kick in and avoid declaring stuff inside the namespace.

Comment: Thanks for the input. No, this isn't something that *I'm* doing. Rather this is what the project is already doing. I just happened to stumble across it because of the issues coming up due to it. I'm not sure why the original author did it this way though.

Comment: @Victor T.: I gave you a suggestion as to how you might correct the situation. But really, you should just fix it so it doesn't do that anymore. Whoever decided to do it that way in the first place made a very bad decision.

Answer (score 1):

I would say you need to change the offending code so that the standard types are no longer defined within `project_namespace`.

It seems to me you have two major issues: [1] you have a catch-all header in `project_all.h` and [2] it's `#include`d inside `namespace project_namespace`.  I'll address the latter first.  If your project has things it wants to put in its own namespace, that's fine, but it should be done as follows:

```
// Foo.h
// includes go here
namespace project_namespace {
    class Foo { ... }
}
// Foo.cpp
// includes go here
namespace project_namespace {
    // Foo implementation goes here
}
```

... in other words, your classes' header and implementation files need to say what namespace the classes belong in, "self-namespacing" as it were.  All your `#include`s are outside a `namespace` because the header file for each class declares the namespaces the class belongs to.  This is the convention used by the standard library.

Now if you still want to use a `project_all.h` you can do so.  Without the namespace -- because each header file will place its declarations in the namespace it wants to (or not).

But it would be better to dispense with `project_all.h`; instead, `#include` the header files individually and make the dependencies explicit.  And if the response is "there are too many header files", that's probably a sign of a high degree of coupling between your components.

I realize this is probably not the answer you wanted, sorry ...

Comment: This is a good response, and I found it helpful nonetheless. I'll see if I can change it to better conform to this pattern. I'd would like to keep the changes needed to a minimum though. I'm guessing the original author had a all.h in there for precompiled header purposes.

Comment: Concerning the precompiled headers:
The `#include`s do document your dependencies; I would argue that is an important function, and one that increases in importance over time, as developers transition onto and off of the team.  
I understand the precompiled header / build-time issue (and I feel your pain), but there are better ways to address this.  Let's say you're interfacing to temperature and humidity sensors.  Each of those I/O interfaces can (and probably should) be packaged into its own DLL; then you don't have to (re)build that code along with your "main" app every time.

Comment: I also understand your reluctance to make a lot of changes at once (and that's a healthy reaction).
My advice would be to make your changes small and incremental.  Better yet, build unit tests around them as you go so you have a regression test suite in place to verify you haven't broken anything.

Comment: Weird question - do you make a distinction between "there are *a lot* of headers" and "there are *too many* headers"? I don't use "...all.hpp", but I tend to separate a few closely- or circularly-dependent classes/template classes, e.g. quaternion/vector/matrix, by forward-declaring them in one header like "math.hpp", and (sometimes) including each separated header from the grouped header and vice versa. Am I right to assume that artificial separation / intentional inter-dependency implies artificial coupling concerns too? Or is there a 'better' approach? (Sorry for the 6-year necropost.)

Comment: I was running out of space, but by that first question, I really meant "too many" vs. "many (for future devs' convenience)" and "many (sub-/headers mutually required for at least basic high-level functionality)". (I can see places where those might diverge, after using plenty of libs like SDL2 with its near-monolithic SDL_video.h at 1.25kl with .5kl includes, SDL_opengl.h at 2kl, etc.) ___ Edit: found [a useful page](https://accu.org/index.php/journals/473) on just this topic, but I'm welcome to opinions anyway.

Comment: @JohnP It depends, I guess.  If on your project you have several libraries that you typically use together -- and therefore you typically `#include` all or none of them -- I could see grouping them in one header file.  (Although I would probably want something a little more descriptive than "math.hpp".)

Comment: My primary concerns would be (1) that the added level of indirection increases difficulty of comprehension for new developers -- which would include me after a few months on a different project -- and (2) that I'd run afoul of the [Interface Segregation Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle).

Comment: FWIW I'm currently calling it "geometry" and generally these become my "forwarding headers" à la `<iosfwd>` as a reasonable number of declarations fill in (whereas the inclusion of all the definitions would be migrated to the equivalent of `<iostream>` for convenience/simplicity on an opt-in basis.) I'm not sure what you meant by "indirection" - just that there's either a fwd or convenience header between two definitions? I appear to be on the right track with ISP in a few areas, like printing, but fully inverted dependency between general linear algebra constructs looks extraordinarily hairy.

Comment: How to solve that particular example is way off-topic (so as not to be a [DenverCoder9](https://xkcd.com/979/): I'll be reading [ISBN 0486474178](http://a.co/2QqIiu0)) but thanks for your time and the resources you posted!