# Is it a good idea to wrap an #include in a namespace block?

Tags: c++, namespaces, include

I have a C header that was written to compile as both C and C++ (it only uses features from the common subset, and uses that `extern "C"` thing).

Problem is, that header declares stuff in the global namespace. I'd rather avoid that for the usual reasons. I thought about doing this:

```
namespace foo {
#include <foo.h>
}
```

Is doing this a good idea? Do I have alternatives that don't include editing the header file?

Comment: Interesting idea. However, if it is a C code, I would leave it where it is : global namespace.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

No, it’s a bad idea. With C++ declarations, it's likely to introduce linker errors as identifiers get declared in the wrong namespace. With C declarations, it works, but it may hide clashes between identifiers in the global namespace (which you were trying to avoid, I guess) until link time; it doesn't *really* put the identifiers in a namespace.

A better idea would be to put your own identifiers in a namespace and avoid defining anything but `main` in the global one.

Comment: +1 I actually ran into a problem like this because a certain open source project decided to do [exactly this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6006602/pulling-c-c-standard-library-into-your-project-namespace-good-idea). The result was that I had to dig through ***numerous*** project and std headers to figure out the root cause. I managed to resolve it but in the end this just ends up being another porting issue to worry about.

Comment: I had a feeling this wasn't quite right, but I couldn't say why. I'm glad I decided to ask here :)

Comment: Congrats on the gold badge :)

Comment: Example of hiding of name clashes until at least assembly (code generation) time: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/

Answer (score 5):

I did this kind of "place it in a namespace" for `<windows.h>` in the late 1990's.

Although not with complete support: it was on the principle of adding support for whatever next I needed when I needed it.

The key to make that work was to check which C library headers were included, and make sure to include them first. It boiled down to 4 such headers, IIRC. Microsoft's love of macros made things difficult, though.

So it can be done in practice for C headers (or C++ restricted to the C-like subset), but at cost of updating your wrapper for every new version of the wrappee, Which is impractical and/or very costly. Not to mention laborious.

In conclusion, no, it's not a good idea. :-)

Speaking from experience.