# Resolve include conflicts (re-definitions) or how to include declared members selectively

Tags: c++

I want to include std::unique_lock and some other names from the <mutex> header, but not std::mutex and other names (which I have a different declaration of - in Relacy Race Detector if you're curious). Which is causing compile errors. How can I do this?

Edit: The compiler errors which occur when RRD and <mutex> are included are:

```
error C2371: 'rl::condition_variable' : redefinition; different basic types C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\mutex    58  1   test_hashtable
error C2371: 'rl::mutex' : redefinition; different basic types  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\mutex    100 1   test_hashtable
error C2371: 'rl::recursive_mutex' : redefinition; different basic types    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\mutex    114 1   test_hashtable
```

Comment: Do you have to have your mutex in std's namespace?

Comment: Did you use `using namespace std;`? Then all members of `std` are introduced in the current scope and you can't un-introduce them. Also provide your compiler errors, please. And are you sure, that the RRD mutex is in `std` too?

Comment: Ah, I see the confusion, no it's in namespace std, but the RRD mutex is also in std (because it's designed to be a drop in replacement for std atomics, mutex and others) but it doesn't include everything like std::unique_lock.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could `#include` RRD into its own namespace :

```
namespace RRD {
  #include <rrd.h>
}
```

This should work unless RRD refers to global-namespace functions (e.g., `::isalnum`).

Then, import classes into your current namespace:

```
#ifdef DETECT_RACE_CONDITIONS
using RRD::std::mutex;
#else
using std::mutex;
#end
using std::unique_lock;
```

Finally, use `mutex` in your code, not `std::mutex`. If you're concerned with things living in the global namespace, you can wrap the above code in its own `namespace`.

Comment: Ok, but now I need to use the mutex in RLD to replace std::mutex and others, how do I do that?

Comment: Added a possible way to use RRD and STD together.

Comment: This will cause lots of problems if RRD is not header only: the compiled symbols are in namespace `std`, not `RRD`, so the linker will not find them. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6670753/46642