# Compilation error when including boost/program_options.hpp

Tags: c++, gcc, boost

This program compiles just fine:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <stdio.h>

#include <boost/program_options.hpp>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    std::cout << "Hello world" << std::endl;
}
```

This program gives a long compilation error:

```
#include <iostream>

namespace cio {
#include <stdio.h>
}

#include <boost/program_options.hpp>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    std::cout << "Hello world" << std::endl;
}
```

The full dump of the compilation error: http://codepad.org/aIcQqkgH

The linux command I'm using to compile the program is: c++ -o main.cpp.o -c main.cpp

Comment: @hosch250 Why? namespace cio { #include <stdio.h> } works just fine, exactly as one might expect. The program doesn't fail to compile until after you add the line: #include <boost/program_options.hpp>

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12324302/is-it-ok-to-put-a-standard-pure-c-header-include-directive-inside-a-namespace (and many others). In short: Don't do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use

```
#include <cstdio>
```

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cstdio

This header is officially required to declare all the legacy C library declarations inside namespace `std`.

However, if you have a "problem" that requires these "solutions", indeed just namespace your own stuff. If it's actually Boost that pollutes the global namespace, then file a bug.

Comment: Is there a version of that for ncurses? #include <cncurses>?

Comment: `ncurses` is not a standard header, the include in a namespace will probably work. the standard explicitly forbids doing anything before including a standard header that changes its meaning.