# How to include the two different versions of the same header?

Tags: c++, header, include, version, conflict

I am writing file conversion code from a proprietary file format to one more generic. My goal is to support multiple versions of the manufacturer's file format.

I have a multiple versions of the same proprietary headers. The headers define various structs which comprise the main file header (the file is simply a large header followed by raw data).

I need to read the first 4 bytes of the source file to determine the file version. The file version, in turn, tells me which version of the C-structs was used to create the file.

The issues are:

1. I can't modify the proprietary headers
2. The headers do not use namespaces or classes
3. There are a good handful of macros defined in the headers

Possible solutions:

- Build different converter binaries for each file version type :-(

  - Inconvenient for both user and developer
- Dynamically load libraries for each version

  - The converter is plugin-oriented, so there's already a lot of this happening

I have tried hacking with namespaces:

```
namespace version1 {
    #include "version1.h"
}

namespace version2 {
    #include "version2.h"
}

int main (void) {
    version1::header *hdr = new version1::header;
    return 0;
}
```

But this won't work because of include guards, and because there are multiple macros are redefined in each header.

Is there an elegant way to handle this?

Comment: The headers -- how `C` are they?  Do you only use the headers, no library or `.c` or `.cpp` files backing them?  You say you cannot modify the headers: can you take the headers as input and code generate derivatives to be compiled?

Comment: They are pure C headers. There aren't even any function declarations, just C-structs.

Comment: @MatsPetersson probably has a reasonable approach then.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use two different source files, together with a forward declaration:

```
// Forward declare in main.cpp:

namespace version1
{
   struct header;
}

namespace version2
{
   struct header;
}
```

---

```
// version1.cpp:

namespace version1
{
      #include <version1.h>
}

version1::header* new_v1_header()
{
   return new version1::header;
}

// other functions using `version1::header`
```

---

```
// version2.cpp:

namespace version2
{
      #include <version2.h>
}

version2::header* new_v2_header()
{
   return new version2::header;
}

// other functions using `version2::header`
```

Another alternative is to implement a wrapper class, which has a base-class that is just an empty shell:

```
class header_base
{
     virtual int func1(char *stuff) = 0; 
     ... many other virtual functions. 
};

// Create implementation of header_v1 or header_v2:
header_base* make_header(unsigned int magic);
```

header_base.cpp:

```
#include "header_v1.h"
#include "header_v2.h"

header_base* make_header(unsigned int magic)
{
    switch(magic)
    {
       case Magic_V1: 
          return new header_v1;
       case Magic_V2: 
          return new header_v2;
       default:
          assert(0);
          return 0;
    }
}
```

and then implement, in two separate

in headerv1.h:

```
class header_v1 : public header_base
{
    int func1(char *stuff);
    ... 
};
```

header_v1.cpp:

```
#include "header1.h"

int header_v1::func1(char *stuff)
{
   ... 
   return 17;
}
```

And similar for header_v2.h and header_v2.cpp.

Comment: This isn't a particularly great idea if the library is not header-only, because it messes with the mangled names. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/6670753/46642.

Comment: Exactly what I would do.  I'd also probably declare an ABC that wraps the functionality declared by the headers, and have 2 concrete derivations of the ABC; one for each version.

Comment: The structs just define hundreds of primitive types, no functions. In order to use the header_base dynamically, I'd have to store a pointer to the top-level struct, then make virtual getters for each of the hundreds of struct members, then implement getters for each member for each derived wrapper class.

Comment: That sounds like the right thing to do is to move the differentiation down a level or three. Or, simply change the actual header files...

Comment: Okay in the end I'm going with your alternative (second) idea... I made a virtual class to serve as an interface to the header and I'll either store (void*) references to the top-level struct so I can compile everything into one binary or fall back to dynamically loading libraries containing the implementation classes.