# C# - Why is ::-operator assosiated with global keyword instead of the dot operator?

Tags: c#, namespaces, global, operator-keyword

Coming from C++ background myself, it takes some time to get used to C#. In C#, one uses the dot operator (.) more often than the ::-operator (the namespace qualifier operator in C#), to access namespace and class scopes.

In C++, one uses the dot operator (.) to access members of an instance of a class. Scope resolution operator (::) on the other hand, is used to access members of a class without an instance of that class. To me, this makes sense and is both logical and consistent.

While I can accept different approach used in C#, there seems to be at least one instance, in which I see an inconsistence. At least, that is how it appears to me. It has to do with the global keyword:

```
global::System.Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
```

Could somebody explain to me why namespace alias qualifier is required to use with global keyword instead of the dot operator?

Comment: Because `global` is a *namespace alias* to the (actually anonymous) global namespace, not a namespace *per se*?

Comment: Always treat resembles between C# and C++ as an accident, not a design goal.  And the odds it does the same inversely proportional to the amount of trouble it causes in C++.  Which is a *lot*, name resolution in C++ is ridiculously complicated.  The Microsoft C++ compiler still has major bugs today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not really common but there are some situations when it's handy.

Imagine you have this a class `System` inside *current* namespace:

```
namespace Test {
    static class System {
        public static Do() { }
    }

    class Foo {
        void foo() {
            System.Do(); // What's this?
        }
    }
}
```

Do you want to make it more complicate? Add an inner class in `System` and call it, for example, `Action`. Of course these are edge cases and probably you won't ever need to use `global::` but language itself has to handle this situation. See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c3ay4x3d.aspx) for more examples.

Global namespace aliases are also useful in another situation: when you reference two DLLs and they have the same namespaces and classes (for example because they simply are the two *versions* of same *stuff*). In that case how can you reference them? Same [problem described here for C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17571872/how-to-include-the-two-different-versions-of-the-same-header). You can change namespace to include version number but it's a pain each time you change it (and VS automatic refactoring AFAIK doesn't work with namespaces) or you can reference them using two aliases. They'll be accessed, for example, like this:

```
Version1::CompanyName.MyNamespace.MyClass
Version2::CompanyName.MyNamespace.MyClass
```

Also note that it's a good practice (to include `global::` namespace) when you're generating code (for example all designers generated code) because you *don't know* in which scenario that code will be compiled (then collisions may occur).

---

Reasoning about `::` and `.` well...it's not a question for SO (unless you're so lucky Eric is having some fun here on SO) but I may guess it's because they're different things. If same operator `.` is used then how can parser understand with `global.System` you want to use global namespace alias and not a class or namespace named `global`? They had to make `global` a reserved keyword and it won't solve the other problem of *conflicting* hierarchies...

Comment: Of course anyone creating their own class named 'System' needs to have their head examined. If you find that you need to use 'global::', then you've probably done something wrong.

Comment: @DaveDoknjas absolutely! It's little bit _worse_ because same consideration applies to properties, inner classes and fields but yes...pretty uncommon.