# what would be the disadvantage for OpenGL functions in namespace gl?

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm currently using [glLoadGen](https://bitbucket.org/alfonse/glloadgen/wiki/Styles) to load OpenGL functions,

there is an option like place all function pointers in `namespace gl`
so that I can use them like `gl::CreateShader( ... )`

what would be the disadvantages for that feature??

It does not pollute global namespace with thoes gl** functions, or macros;
but I'm afraid there are some potential disadvantages...

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6670738/is-it-a-good-idea-to-wrap-an-include-in-a-namespace-block) is related.

Comment: I don't see why would you want to use this option. You'll need to type extra `::` each time and you wont be able to copy-paste GL code directly from other sources. You say that this option is good because it does not pollute global namespace, but the pollution is not a problem if all names have proper prefixes.

Comment: @CoryKramer Related, but not closely as that's not what glLoadGen does (depending on options).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: "*you wont be able to copy-paste GL code directly from other sources*" That sounds like a really good reason to *use it*. Copy-and-paste coding is a *bad thing*.

Comment: @NicolBolas You're right indeed, copy-paste coding is bad. But that's not a proper reason to intentionally use unconventional function names. Also, sometimes copy-pasting may be useful: OP may want to copy and run code with GL function calls just to learn it. Or he may need to just copy ver long function name from GL docs. Surely it doesn't take too much time to add `::`, but for me this option still seems like unnecessary overcomplication.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I'm using auto completion in vim. actually just for a little performance, like not showing gl*** functions on every completion list

Comment: @ehwank Sorry, now I understand why you want to use it. I guess there is no major disadvantages, only those tiny ones I've listed.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat thanks a lot. I was worried if it could be such a disaster in future.

Comment: If something goes wrong with it, you can always use vim (or just sed) to replace `gl::` with `gl` and reconfigure glLoadGen.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you would not want to do this because they will no longer follow the C language binding naming conventions used universally. The whole namespace problem was already solved in a language agnostic way by tacking `GL_` onto the beginning of constants and `gl` onto the beginning of functions.

You are free to do whatever you want here, but the global namespace in a language like C or C++ is already polluted by the underlying library you linked to. For example, on Windows you have all of the functions from GL 1.1 just sitting there with the standard C language bindings for names. This is a set of about 400 functions that you get by including the platform's OpenGL header.

Comment: Considering the various bindings to non-C languages, I would hesitate to call this convention "used universally". LWJGL gives each OpenGL version and extension its own separate pseudo-namespace. OpenTK puts OpenGL in a `GL` class, but removes the `gl` and `GL_` prefixes that become redundant. It even renames OpenGL enumerators in accord with C# conventions. Given that there are many ways to bind OpenGL to a language, why should C++ *have to* follow C's lead?

Comment: @NicolBolas: Don't get me wrong, I am well aware that many, many language bindings do away with this convention. My point here was actually that by including `gl/gl.h` from C or C++, you're going to have a bunch of functions dragged in with the original `gl*` convention. If the intention by segregating everything into its own namespace was simplicity, in this situation the opposite is accomplished. You would need to write your own header and ensure that no part of your software includes the platform header to avoid this.

Comment: "*You would need to write your own header and ensure that no part of your software includes the platform header to avoid this.*" Yes. Which is something I accounted for *when I wrote that feature* into glLoadGen. And that's a very common thing about OpenGL loaders. Virtually all of them will prevent you from including `gl/gl.h` manually, and they'll fail to work if you try to include that header *before* including theirs. Even GLEW's headers do that. This problem is already accounted for. Even the `wgl.h` issue.

Comment: It's really not, at all. Take for example OS X. It has `gl.h` and `gl3.h`, which are intended to be mutually exclusive. The case where both headers are included can be detected, the case where only `gl.h` is included and the rest of the software uses the interfaces provided by `gl3.h` ... that's not. You can easily wind up with one module of code using the original C language bindings and another using your custom C++ bindings without ever knowing it just as the situation arises on OS X.

Comment: "*You can easily wind up with one module of code using the original C language bindings and another using your custom C++ bindings without ever knowing it*" Sure, that can happen. So what? One part of an app can use GLEW while another uses glBinding, while a third uses `gl.h` by itself. In the end, it all talks to C using the same functions. So where exactly is the issue?

Comment: There's a huge one. One part of the code is dispatched through your language bindings, the rest goes through something lower-level. If they were ever to deviate because you wanted to add a debug layer / API wrapping functionality or even thread-local-storage like OpenGL32.dll uses, code that was originally functionally identical is no longer -- but the program continues to compile and link. If you cannot prevent someone from errantly including the platform's original bindings and using standard bindings, you have to write additional validation somewhere in your deployment steps.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121981/discussion-between-nicol-bolas-and-andon-m-coleman).